# Area under line with discrete data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

[image]

Generated with

```
all$lvl <- factor(all$Criteria, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
ggplot(all, aes(x=Date, y=Users, color=Answer, group=Answer)) + 
geom_point(size=1.5) + geom_line(size=1.5) +
theme_hc() + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + facet_grid(.~lvl) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

The line connects the values from my dataframe with **discrete** values for both `x` and `y`. How do I fill the area below the lines? With `geom_area` I get weird results:

[image]

```
geom_area(linetype=1, size=0.2, color="black", aes(fill=Answer))
```

I suppose this is because `geom_area` is for continuous values. Is there a way to do this for a discrete data set? Superimposing the line makes the weirdness more obvious:

[image]

I tried other values for `stat` other than the `identity` default, without success. As I understand it, `identity` shouldn't change the data...

Comment: You should include sample data to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What precisely is "weird" about the results? What exactly do you expect the plot to look like for your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_area` defaults to `position = "stack"`, which is why the two colour regions are stacked instead of overlapping. Try `position = "identity"`.